# Proxy doen't work on production version in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, http, proxy, cors, ionic3

I have an Ionic 2 app that makes request to an API.

I had to configure a proxy to connect to the API because CORS problems.

I did it and it works in browser and on device in dev mode (ionic run), but it doesn't work in production mode.

This is my configuration in `ionic.config.json` :

```
"proxies": [
        {
            "path": "/api",
            "proxyUrl": "here is the root endpoint"
        }
]
```

It works well with:
`ionic serve --watch` and `ionic cordova run android --consolelogs --device --livereload`

It doesn't work after build with: `ionic cordova build android --prod --release`

For the moment, before I build a production version, I must alternate manually (with the IDE search engine) between the proxy and a constant in which I have the root endpoint, but I need to be able to use the proxy for dev and not have to change to hand the endpoints before deploying to production.

Any ideas?

Thank's!

Comment: android webview doesnt enforce cors... are you sure it is a cors problem?

Comment: @SurajRao Console log: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Mm in Android, but running `ionic run android --consolelogs --device --livereload` it works with proxy.

Comment: I haven't seen this before.. Guess you have to implement cors

Comment: Also how did you get console logs from prod build?

Comment: In production i didn't get console errors. It just doesnt work and I don't know what is the error. But in pruduction, the proxy obviously does not work because there is not a server running acting as an intermediary

Comment: Anybody able to solve this issue, I am facing the same issue. Work fine on my local but when I deploy it on my dev environment I am facing the CORS issue